# How can I sum across objects in the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to calculate the difference of BTC between arrayOne and arrayTwo , just like:

```
if(BTC = BTC)(BTC Value arrayOne - BTC arrayTwo)
```

How should I do this using the map function in JavaScript?

```
arrayOne [
  {
    "BTC": 1.21980
  },
  {
    "ETH": 8.32983  
  }
];

arrayTwo = [
  {
    "BTC": 0.21980
  },
  {
    "ETH": 4.32983  
  }
]
```

I want the return value to be like this:

```
        result = [
            {
                "BTC": 1
            },
            {
                "ETH": 4    
            }
        ]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Is your data structure fixed? This would be much easier if the “arrays” were just objects instead of arrays of objects with one key each

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the `{"BTC": 1}` object pretty easily:

```js
var arrayOne = [
            {
                "BTC": 1.21980
            },
            {
                "ETH": 8.32983  
            }
        ];

var arrayTwo = [
            {
                "BTC": 0.21980
            },
            {
                "ETH": 4.32983  
            }
        ];

var diff = arrayOne[0]["BTC"] - arrayTwo[0]["BTC"];
var resultBTC = { "BTC":  diff};
```

Now you can easily continue from there to create your `result` array.

Answer (score 0):

if u want the difference between both the BTC and ETH in one array all you have to do is

var differenceBTC = arrayOne[0]["BTC"] - arrayTwo[0]["BTC"]

var differenceETH = arrayOne[1]["ETH"] - arrayTwo[1]["ETH"]

var result = [differenceBTC, differenceETH]

Comment: BTC and ETH are in **two different JSON objects** in arrayOne, same for array 2. For that, it should be `arrayOne[0]["BTC"]` and `arrayTwo[0]["BTC"]`

Comment: Unless you change Jordy's array